# Slow UITableView Scrolling from JSON

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview

My UITableView scrolls really slowly when I load from a local JSON. The images are being loaded from a external URL. I first try loading the JSON in my viewWillAppear method:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,0), ^{
    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"HomePage" ofType:@"json"];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    self.titleLabels = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
});
```

And in my tableView (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath, I have the following:

```
    HomeTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

if(cell == nil) {
    [tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"HomeCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
}

NSDictionary *titleLabels = [self.titleLabels objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSString *label = [titleLabels objectForKey:@"Heading"];
NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[titleLabels objectForKey:@"Image"]];

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL]];

cell.label.text = label;
cell.imageView.image = image;
cell.cardView.frame = CGRectMake(10, 5, 300, 395);

return cell;
```

I am just wondering why the table view is scrolling very slowly. If anyone could shed some light on this, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: This line `UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL]];` causes the issue. It's a synchronous call from main thread, so it'll block the UI until the image data is retrieved. Use lazy loading for images

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL]]
```

This is what is causing the slow scrolling in your app. You are making a network call for the cell.imageView.image property.  Since you are calling the `[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL]];` ON THE MAIN THREAD, the app needs to wait for the network call to finish, only then it can scroll farther.

The keypoint here is, you are doing all the networking calls on the main thread, and all touches will be delayed untill all the cells have been completely loaded.

This is not recommended, at all.

---

A better approach :

(1). is to make the networking call, only for the VISIBLE CELLS on the screen. 
Follow this tutorial -- > [How to Make Faster UITableViewCell Scrolling](http://www.raywenderlich.com/19788/how-to-use-nsoperations-and-nsoperationqueues) by RayWenderLich

(2) [Apple's Sample Code, which shows this in action](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/lazytableimages/introduction/intro.html)

(3) Load all the images beforehand and store it in an array, after viewDidLoad

Comment: There is also this convenient library to use once: https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage. Use the library after you read the links above of course.